# If Statement jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I want to check if text exists in a tr, if there is no text, I want to change the CSS of two other elements.

For example:

```
if div#id table tbody tr == "" then
   set CSS div#id border:0; & set div#id2  border radius:7px;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, I'll write your code for you:

```
if ($("div#id table tbody tr").length == 0) {
    $("div#id").css("border", "0px");
    $("div#id2").css("border-radius", "7px");
}
```

Also, this has nothing to do with "Java."

---

By the way, welcome to StackOverflow. The most likely reason you've received so many downvotes is that your question is basically "asking someone to write your code for you," and this won't help anyone in the future.

It sounds like you're trying to learn jQuery and/or JavaScript. If so, I'd really recommend the [jQuery Cookbook by O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596159788.do). I've been reviewing it lately, and it's really a pretty good book for getting started.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uACTx/3/. Note that this is invalid because text should never be inside a TR directly, but it should still work. You could check for the existence of a TD instead, might be better.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I taught myself CSS and HTML because they were logical to read, unfortunately I cannot easily read jQuery but acknowledge how powerful of a platform it is... I will look into that book.